# Firebase Database Functions Rules

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Trying to add a simple trigger to write to another table the timestamp whenever the table is written to.  Problem is the data is from a JSON file that is an Array of Json objects.  More complex than this but here is the psuedo-data.

```
category 
   - 0 
       - name: "Name0"
       - dsiplayname: "Name of Obj 0"
   - 1
       - name: "Name1"
       - dsiplayname: "Name of Obj 1"
```

The function I wrote is this

```
'use strict';
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.touch = functions.database.ref('/{category}').onWrite(
    (change, context) => admin.database().ref('/category_date').set(context.timestamp));
```

If I use this then a single write triggers the timestamp hundreds of times.  So how do I write this to trigger on an Edit /category/[any array item]/{any column}
or an Insert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a simple mistake in your database trigger that is causing it to fire for **any** write to **any** table - including your `/category_date` table... triggering the function causing another write to the `/category_date` table... which triggers the function again and causes another write to the `/category_date` table... which triggers the (*etc...*)

This code:

```
functions.database.ref('/{category}').onWrite(
```

will fire for **ALL** paths, because you have the word `category` as a `{parameter}` instead of an exact match. Change it to:

```
functions.database.ref('/category/{category_index}').onWrite(
```

or even just:

```
functions.database.ref('/category').onWrite(
```

and that should hopefully fix it.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work, functions.database.ref('/category').onWrite( the trigger never fires not sure if the functions.database.ref('/category/{category_index}').onWrite( will work because that endless loop seems to have killed my database quota for functions so I get quota limit exceeded.